# How to sort specific set of rows with specific column?

Tags: matlab, sorting

In Matlab, I would like to sort first 3 rows of a matrix `A` with column 2 and then next 3 rows without changing the first three rows again with column 2. 
e.g. for the matrix is below

```
A = [1 6 50;
     5 2 50;
     7 1 50;
     2 5 53;
     5 1 53;
     7 3 53]
```

I want to get

```
B = [7 1 50;
     5 2 50;
     1 6 50;
     5 1 53;
     7 3 53;
     2 5 53;]
```

Later, with the same logic, I would like to sort a matrix with 100 rows.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by combining the `sortrows` method with the submatrix operation:

```
A(1:3,:) = sortrows(A(1:3,:), 2)
A(4:6,:) = sortrows(A(4:6,:), 2)
...
```

If your matrix is larger, you can do it with a simple for loop:

```
for i = 1:3:100
    A(i:i+2,:) = sortrows(A(i:i+2,:), 2)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias for the answer. I have received one more answer for this question from another forum.

for k = 1:3:size(A, 1)
  [dummy, index] = sort(A(k:k+2, 2));
  A(k:k+2, :)    = A(index + k - 1, :);

end

Comment: It looks like this approach should work as well, but I think the `sortrows` approach might be a bit more readable ;)